# Torsion of $H_{n-1}$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Suppose $X$ is a non-orientable manifold. Using Universal Coefficient Theorem (UCT) for homology, we can get that the torsion of $H_{n-1}$ is a cyclic group of order $2$. I am looking for a proof of this fact without using UCT for homology.

Attempts:

- Using UCT for cohomology I get that $H_{n-1}$ is a sum of a free part and a finite abelian group of even order.
- Using Bockstein homomorphism, but I did not get anything.

Comment: UCT = Universal Coefficient Theorem

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming $X$ is closed. Almost always (i.e. always except *possibly* in some scenarios for $n=4$ when $X$ is not smoothable), $X$ admits a homotopy-equivalent CW-complex which has a single $n$-cell. Now look at the chain-complex differential $d:C_n(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}\to C_{n-1}(X)$ and argue that $d$ must send the generator to twice a generator (this was mentioned after Corollary III.3.28 of Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*). Indeed, the fact $H_n(X;\mathbb{Z}_2)\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$ forces $d$ to send the generator to $2m$ times a generator (for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$), while the facts $H_n(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2k+1})=0$ and $H_n(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2k})\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$ force $m=1$.

Comment: I don't understand. What is the generator of $C_{n-1}(X)$?

Comment: There may be many -- the point is that $d$ maps *the* generator to twice of *one* generator, and that is the only source of torsion because there are no other generators in $C_n(X)$.

Comment: Why can't $d$ send the top generator to $4$ times a generator?  That would still give $H_n(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Oh right, in fact we have $H_n(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2k})\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$ for all integers $k$, which forbids your option.